# Why spark.read.parquet() runs 2 jobs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file, named `test.parquet`. It contains some integers. When I read it using following code:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("test.parquet")

df.show(false)

+---+
|id |
+---+
|11 |
|12 |
|13 |
|14 |
|15 |
|16 |
|17 |
|18 |
|19 |
+---+
```

In logs it shows 2 jobs that were executed. They are as follows:

[image]

One is `parquet` job and another one is `show` job. Whereas, when I read parquet file using following code:

```
val df = spark.read.schema(StructType(List(StructField("id",LongType,false)))).parquet("test.parquet")

df.show(false)

+---+
|id |
+---+
|11 |
|12 |
|13 |
|14 |
|15 |
|16 |
|17 |
|18 |
|19 |
+---+
```

Only one job is executed, i.e., `show`:

[image]

So, my question is:

1. Why first approach executes 2 jobs whereas second approach executes only one ?
2. And, why second approach is faster than the first one ?

Comment: If you are performing those commands sequentially, first you are load then showing the df. Thats 2 different tasks. If you ask spark to read that file again. Well he already has its execution plan, even the data if the garbage collector did clean up so the only task that spark will be performing is showing the data.

Comment: @eliasah Are you talking about why second approach is faster ? Because when I reversed the order of execution of above 2 approaches (sequentially) then also second approach was faster than the first approach.

Comment: Well that what my comment says

Comment: Ok...I got that! Do you know the reason for first approach executing 2 jobs ?

Comment: I have also explained that in my comment. And as a matter of fact, the data is really to small to compare genuinely.

Comment: So, you mean when we provide `schema` before loading data...we are providing execution plan to Spark ?

Comment: I didn't say that. Assaf's answer completes what I said for the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark reads the file twice.
 1- To evolve the schema 
 2- To create the dataFrame

Once the schema will be generated, the dataFrame will be created which is fast.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! But I still don't understand as to why first approach executes 2 jobs ?

Comment: Answer is in your question brother.. In the second approach you have defined the schema - StructField("id",LongType,false)). Thats the reason it creates only one job to load the file.

But in the first approach- you are not defining the schema. Spark sql will generate the schema by reading the file. This will be first job. Then, the whole file will be loaded to create a DataFrame. This will be second job

Comment: Thanks! I got that, after I had discussion with @eliasah.